# Using a controller to remotely alternate the direction of a peristaltic pump

Tags: control-engineering, pumps

I am working with a peristaltic pump to move liquid to/from a reservoir through a closed loop of tubing. The motor can rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise when set with either of the directional buttons below.

[image]

The direction of rotation can also be controlled remotely using contacts #1/2 in the green barrier strip below:

[image]

I have little experience with this kind of work. Would this be a simple enough task to connect, program and use a controller to alternate the direction of the motor for some time interval?

Even if someone could describe the process for me in simple terms, it might be helpful in my understanding of how to approach the challenge.

Comment: I suggest using a simple DIY microcontroller the drive the input signals on the green connector. I hope you have access to some type of documentation. Also consider a software tool like Labview. Alternatively the RS232 9 pin connector might also provide capability to control the pump. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the manufacturers spec sheet if possible. This will detail the voltages, pin configuration, and more control details.
2. If the spec sheet specifies serial commands like 706Astor mentioned, you may be able to use a usb-to-serial converter and a serial console like [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for testing it. You could then send serial commands via [python](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) or other programming language.
3. If serial is not an option, test the inputs with an [alligator clip](http://www.apogeekits.com/images/alligator_leads_red_black.jpg) or other testing leads. I assume based on the diagram that connecting 1 and 2 makes it run counter-clockwise, leaving them disconnected is clockwise. Connecting 3 and 4 makes it run, disconnecting makes it stop. Connect a 1.5v AA or AAA battery up to 5(+side) and 6(-side) to test its speed at 1.5/5 = 30% speed.
4. If your tests work out and you now understand the operation, and all you want to do is change the direction at some interval, you might be able to use a [cheap dc timer relay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012FSL2GK) to connect contacts 1 and 2.
5. If you need more control or more adjustment on the timing, you will want to get an [Arduino UNO](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). They are very popular with lots of tutorials and internet community support. There are also some good tutorials on [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/category/learn-arduino).

Comment: The [spec sheet](https://www.labmakelaar.com/fjc_documents/minipuls3_manual.pdf) does specify serial inputs and specifically  RS422A/RS485 transmitters
and receivers. Does this mean I could use a [converter](https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Professional-Adapter-Retention-ICUSB422/dp/B002VY523I) to operate the pump from a laptop using a python code?

Comment: Yeah that should work great. I found some python libraries that may be of interest:
  https://github.com/echo-oddly/gsioc_controller
  https://github.com/daan/gilson215